# PySpark: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name ... contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm trying to load Parquet data into `PySpark`, where a column has a space in the name:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('my_parquet_dump')
df.select(df['Foo Bar'].alias('foobar'))
```

Even though I have aliased the column, I'm still getting this error and error propagating from the `JVM` side of `PySpark`.  I've attached the stack trace below.

Is there a way I can load this parquet file into `PySpark`, without pre-processing the data in Scala, and without modifying the source parquet file?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/usr/local/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o864.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "Foo Bar" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.checkConversionRequirement(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.checkFieldName(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$checkFieldNames$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$$anonfun$checkFieldNames$1.apply(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:575)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.checkFieldNames(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(ParquetFileFormat.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2803)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2823)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2800)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-9d7c55a5465c> in <module>()
----> 1 spark.sql("SELECT `Foo Bar` as hey FROM df limit 10").take(1)

/usr/local/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in take(self, num)
    474         [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
    475         """
--> 476         return self.limit(num).collect()
    477 
    478     @since(1.3)

/usr/local/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    436         """
    437         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 438             port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    439         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    440 

/usr/local/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'Attribute name "Foo Bar" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\\n\\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;'
```

Comment: Your stacktrace says `"SELECT \`Foo Bar\` as hey`, which is valid SparkSQL

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried,

```py
df = df.withColumnRenamed("Foo Bar", "foobar")
```

When you select the column with an alias you're still passing the wrong column name through a select clause.

Comment: The same error is still produced, it looks like it's impossible to read without patching Spark's parquet reader https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2dd37d827f2e443dcb3eaf8a95437d179130d55c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L565-L572

Comment: @munro did you figure out any solution, all solutions in both topics here in stack overflow doesn't work.
Is there any way i can edit the parquet files with any other tool?

Comment: This solution works for me, just need to repeat for all columns that have a space. Important to assign back to the variable: df, without that it continues to fail with the same error.

Comment: It's weird that it works for some people and not for others. It doesn't work for me. You can see the full example at https://github.com/lynxkite/lynxkite/issues/253. Maybe it depends on what happens after `withColumnRenamed()`? If it worked for you, what exactly worked for you?

Comment: I am downvoting this solution because while in general it makes sense it doesn't work in this particular case. You can rename columns all day but it doesn't help if you have spaces in the source parquet.

Comment: @prakharjain , and for those with MY problem -- in my case, the code bringing up this error was in Azure Synapse Analytics, attempting to read a table in dedicatedp1 ... that had spaces in some column names.  None of the pyspark solutions worked, and I solved the problem in SQL:  creating a COPY of the table in dedicatedp1, where columnnames had underlines, instead of spaces.

Comment: @prakharjain -- in hindsight:  for a long-lasting table, it would have been better to CREATE A VIEW under database dedicatedp1, or if logic required, a stored procedure:  dedicatedp1 supports T-SQL standard stuff (including INFORMATION_SCHEMA).

Answer (score 1):

I tried @ktang 's method and it worked for me as well. I'm working with SQL and Python, so it may be different for you, but it worked nonetheless.

Ensure there are no spaces in your column names/headers. Despite the list of characters provided in the error message, space ( ) doesn't seem to be acceptable by Pyspark.

I was initially using:

```
master_df = spark.sql(f'''
SELECT occ.num, 'Occ Event' AS `Event Type`,
...
```

Changing the space ( ) in Event Type to an underscore (_) worked:

```
master_df = spark.sql(f'''
SELECT occ.num, 'Occ Event' AS `Event_Type`,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution..

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.select([col(c).alias(
        c.replace( '(', '')
        .replace( ')', '')
        .replace( ',', '')
        .replace( ';', '')
        .replace( '{', '')
        .replace( '}', '')
        .replace( '\n', '')
        .replace( '\t', '')
        .replace( ' ', '_')
    ) for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: For other pySpark newbies like me, don't forget to add "from pyspark.sql.functions import col"

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed in [Spark 3.3.0 release](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27442) (I tested).