# Spark Dataframe column name change does not reflect

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to rename some special characters from my spark dataframe. For some weird reason, it shows the updated column name when I print the schema, but any attempt to access the data results in an error complaining about the old column name. Here is what I am trying:

```
# Original Schema
upsertDf.columns

# Output: ['col 0', 'col (0)', 'col {0}', 'col =0', 'col, 0', 'col; 0']

for c in upsertDf.columns:
    upsertDf = upsertDf.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace(" ", "_").replace("(","__").replace(")","__").replace("{","___").replace("}","___").replace(",","____").replace(";","_____").replace("=","_"))
upsertDf.columns

# Works and returns expected result
# Output: ['col_0', 'col___0__', 'col____0___', 'col__0', 'col_____0', 'col______0']

# Print contents of dataframe
# Throws error for original attribute name "
upsertDf.show()

AnalysisException: 'Attribute name "col 0" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\\n\\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;'
```

I have tried other options to rename the column (using alias etc...) and they all return the same error. Its almost as if the show operation is using a cached version of the schema but I can't figure out how to force it to use the new names.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this minimal example (using your renaming code, ran in a `pyspark` shell version 3.3.1):

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test")],
    ['col 0', 'col (0)', 'col {0}', 'col =0', 'col, 0', 'col; 0']
)

df.columns
['col 0', 'col (0)', 'col {0}', 'col =0', 'col, 0', 'col; 0']

for c in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace(" ", "_").replace("(","__").replace(")","__").replace("{","___").replace("}","___").replace(",","____").replace(";","_____").replace("=","_"))

df.columns
['col_0', 'col___0__', 'col____0___', 'col__0', 'col_____0', 'col______0']

df.show()
+-----+---------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
|col_0|col___0__|col____0___|col__0|col_____0|col______0|
+-----+---------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
| test|     test|       test|  test|     test|      test|
+-----+---------+-----------+------+---------+----------+
```

As you see, this executes successfully. So your renaming functionality is OK.

Since you haven't shared all your code (how `upsertDf` is defined), we can't really know exactly what's going on. But looking at your error message, this comes from `ParquetSchemaConverter.scala` in a Spark version earlier than `3.2.0` (this error message changed in `3.2.0`, see [SPARK-34402](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34402)).

Make sure that you read in your data and then immediately rename the columns, without doing any other operation.

Comment: I have been reading up on this the past couple of hours, and I think you are right that this is a parquet reader error, not a Spark error. I should have specified this in my question. I don't see a workaround here, other than not using Parquet since the error happens at read.

Comment: If you read up on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804534/pyspark-org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-attribute-name-contains-inv) it seems like renaming your columns should do the trick. Is your `upsertDf` simply the result from `spark.read.parquet`?

Comment: Yes. upsertDf is the result of spark.read.parquet. And I did try renaming the columns, but it looks like that doesn't work whatever option you choose when the underlying source of data is parquet. From what I understand the "conversion" of col names happens when data is read and that's where the error is coming from so it's pretty much unavoidable.